# Link between $L^1$ convergence and equi-integrable

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, compactness

Let $Q$ a bounded regular subset of $\mathbb{R}^d$, equipped with the Lebesgue measure, denoted $\mu$.

I believe that Dunford Pettis theorem adapted to this simple space gives that a sequence $f_n \in L^1(Q)$ is **equi-integrable** if and only if the sequence **$f_n$ is weakly compact sequence in $L^1(Q)$** (i.e $\{ f_n, \ n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ is a compact set of $L^1(Q))$

Let us remember that the equi-integrability of the sequence means that for all $\epsilon>0$, there exists $\delta >0$, such that for all $A \subset Q$ measurable with $\mu(A) \leq \delta$, we have :

$$\int_Q |f_n| \ \mathrm{d} x \leq \epsilon, \quad \forall n \in \mathbb{N}.$$

Now, let $f_n$ a sequence in $L^1(Q)$ that is weakly convergent in $L^1(Q)$ i.e :

$$\int_Q f_n \varphi \ \mathrm{d} x \underset{n \rightarrow 0}{\longrightarrow} \int_Q f_0 \varphi \ \mathrm{d} x, \quad \forall \varphi \in L^\infty(Q), \quad f_0 \in L^1(Q)$$

I was wondering if there is a way to prove that $f_n$ is equi-integrable **without using Dunford Pettis theorem** which would solve the problem instantly since my sequence is weakly convergent therefore weakly compact.

Comment: Other than reproducing the proof (one of which is in [these](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC4QFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.openstarts.units.it%2Fdspace%2Fbitstream%2F10077%2F4777%2F1%2FDiestelRendMat23.pdf&ei=hyCzUty6LaqqyAGX44DgAQ&usg=AFQjCNEMsYp4v9o0D0Gg0Kn2CA9_Fb8vKQ&bvm=bv.58187178,d.aWc) notes), I don't see how.